# Zend Framework - File encoding

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding

I've just started to use the Zend framework for my php development, but I've run in to a problem. 
I'm building a site in a non-english language and therefor I'm using the utf-8 character encoding.
The problem is that Zend seems to encode it's autogenerated files with a different encoding. 
So my question is, can I change the encoding for the files? or are the files encoded differntly when I open them in notepad++?

Comment: Which files are you talking about? ZF doesn't generate files except from zf cli tool. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Which autogenerated files do you mean, and what makes you think they are in a different encoding? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `UTF-8` in file encoding and HTML `<meta>` tag.

Comment: Okey, I've got the meta tag correct. The problem is when I open an autogenerated file in Notepad++. I don't get it in utf-8 so I have to manually change it for evry file?